# Powershell - search through CSV and return only rows with specific error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that returns only the rows that have a specific entry in one of the columns but struggling a bit.
The CSV has 2 relevant columns, the ID and the Error. 
At the moment I have this:

```
$ImportFile = Import-csv X:\errorlist.csv
$Error = $userobject.Error
$ID = $userobject.ID
 $ErrorMessage1 = "Error1"

 foreach($test in $ImportFile) 
  {
   $field1 = $test.Error
   $field2 = $test.ID
     Echo "$field1, $field2" 
  } Where-Object {$_.Error -like $ErrorMessage1}
```

However the echo still returns everything in the csv even with the Where-Object.
I'm trying to run a ForEach because ultimately where I have the echo I'm going to insert a SQL script that uses the ID information in the csv to fix specific errors. Therefore I think I need to keep the foreach to process each sql script in turn, unless anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the rows from the CSV before you run the SQL:

```
Import-Csv X:\errorlist.csv |
    Where-Object { $_.Error -like $ErrorMessage } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Don't use aliases in scripts, use the real cmdlet names. Makes maintenance easier.
        Write-Host ('{0}, {1}' -f $_.Error,$_.ID)

        # Run your SQL cmd here.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, this will check for $ErrorMessage1 in the ID or Error columns:

```
Import-csv X:\errorlist.csv | 
Where-Object {$_.Error -like "*$ErrorMessage1*" -or $_.ID -like "*$ErrorMessage1*"}
```

Comment: I'd make it `-like "*$ErrorMessage1*"` or `-eq $ErrorMessage1`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should have expanded a bit what my ultimate goal is going to be... I'm trying to run a ForEach because ultimately where I have the echo I'm going to insert a SQL script that uses the ID information in the csv to fix specific errors. Therefore I think I need to keep the foreach to process each sql script in turn, unless anyone has a better idea?

Comment: @TimRowsell You can pipe to foreach-object and use an IF statement inside of it.

Comment: @TimRowsell you ought to include this information in your original post; knowing what additional processing needs to happen will help people give the best advise possible.

Comment: @ShayLevy - yes good idea. Apologies for the lack of info in the first post, this is literally the first powershell script I've tried writing and learning fast there are a whole lot of different options in powershell that depend on other factors!

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop operates independent of the `Where-object`, so you all you're doing is dumping the contents of the CSV file to the console.

You can shorten this up a lot by just pumping the data through the pipeline. This will filter your CSV records down to just the ones that meet your criteria.

```
$ErrorMessage1 = "Error1"
$allerrors = Import-csv X:\errorlist.csv|where-object {$_.error -eq $ErrorMessage1}
$allerrors;
```